# Django Testing outputs in the terminal

Tags: python, django

I am running a django test using selenium. Everything really works fine however when I look at the terminal it returns this outputs "None" and "3" as shown in the picture

[image]

I want to remove those as it consume too much space when running so many tests.

I am using python 3.5.1 and djnago 1.9.1

and my code for testing is this:

```
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.testing import StaticLiveServerTestCase
    from django.test import TestCase, LiveServerTestCase

    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

    from login.tests import LogInReusablesScript as LRS , LogInTestFT as LTFT

    from unittest import skip

    import time
    import inspect

    # Create your tests here.
    # Command Line: python manage.py test crew_menu.crew_admin.rank_management

    # python manage.py test crew_menu.crew_admin.rank_management.tests.RankManagementEmptyTestListPage
    class RankManagementEmptyTestListPage(StaticLiveServerTestCase):
        # Used LTFT because LRS already inherits the appended json all throughout
        fixtures = ['login_users.json', 'bio.json']

        def setUp(self):
            self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
            self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)
            self.url = '/crew-menu/crew-admin/rank-management/'

        def tearDown(self):
            self.browser.quit()

        def set_goToListPage(self):
            # self._setup_login_with_access
            # User Logs in
            self.browser.get(self.live_server_url) # .get is tells the browser to go to a new page
            # Type a user's user name in the field
            username_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('username')
            username_field.send_keys('adgc')
            # Type a user's password in the field
            password_field = self.browser.find_element_by_name('password')
            password_field.send_keys('adgcadgc')
            # Click the login button
            login = self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name('button')
            login.click()
            time.sleep(2)
            # Server goes to the Rank Management List Page
            self.browser.get(self.live_server_url+self.url)
            time.sleep(2)
            # System checks the title of the current page if it is Rank Management
            self.assertIn('Rank Management', self.browser.title)

        def test_IsEmpty(self):
            # User Goes to the the Rank List Page
            self.set_goToListPage()
            time.sleep(1)
            # System checks the output if the table is empty
            tr = self.browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("tr")
            self.assertIn('No records found', tr[1].text)
```

Comment: Find in your code, where you're printing/logging these values and remove/comment those lines. What's the problem?

Comment: Show the code for the test that's generating these values.

Comment: Replace any `print` calls with logging at loglevel debug. When you run your tests you can disable logging at level < critical, for instance.

Comment: Please check added comments